# Scalatest "At least one" instead for Forall

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, scalacheck

I wrote this test method in Scala to test a REST service.

```
@Test def whenRequestProductInfo() {
  // When Request Product Info
  forAll { (productId: Int) =>
      val result = mockMvc().perform(get(s"/products/$productId")
        .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType(APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8)))
        .andExpect(status.isOk)
        .andExpect(content.contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8))
        .andReturn;

      val productInfo = mapper.readValue(result.getResponse.getContentAsString, classOf[ProductInfo])

      // At least one is not null
      // assert(productInfo.getInventoryInfo != null)
  }
}
```

But I want to test **that at least one productInfo.getInventoryInfo is not null** instead of **every productInfo.getInventoryInfo is not null**.

Comment: But you *do* want it to be for all product ids, correct? ie. for all product ids, each has inventory info with at least one element that is not null? Is `getInventoryInfo` a collection?

Comment: No exactly. I want to find at least one product id with inventoryInfo!=null

Comment: forAll in this case is using the default Int generator for values (I think). I am not sure that this is what you want. Are you sure you do not want to check for one specific value? Have you looked at "whenever"? It might help you to narrow what you are looking for and still use generators. Check out http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/generator_driven_property_checks for whenever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have a list of product ids:

```
val productIds: List[Int] = ???
```

We ought to factor the conversion from `productId` to `productInfo` into another `val`. (I would think this method or something similar would exist in your code elsewhere).

```
val inventoryInfo = productIds.map { case productId =>
    val result = mockMvc().perform(get(s"/products/$productId")
        .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType(APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8)))
        .andExpect(status.isOk)
        .andExpect(content.contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8))
        .andReturn

    val productInfo = mapper.readValue(result.getResponse.getContentAsString, classOf[ProductInfo])
    productInfo.getInventoryInfo
 }
```

Now we have a list of inventory info, whatever type that is. We can use `atLeast` to check that at least one inventory info from the collection is not `null`.

```
atLeast(1, inventoryInfo) should not be null
```

It doesn't seem like ScalaTest has any curried version of this like with `forAll`, so the syntax is much different and not quite as nice if you need to do a bunch of computations.

Answer (score 2):

forAll can be passed configuration for the number of successful evaluations needed and number of failed evaluations allowed. This should accomplish what you are looking for. [Documentation here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/generator_driven_property_checks) at the end of the page.

Example:

```
forAll (minSuccessful(1)) { (productId: Int) =>  ...
```